# How to select the parent elements of child elements containing specific text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've solved my original problem (painfully) but would like to know if there's a better solution (jQuery must have a better way to do this). I'm working with nested tables (SharePoint) and trying to select rows where a child cell contains specific text. I've worked up a simplified example below (and is also on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpZyn/6/)

In this example I'm trying to add the class "red-row" to the rows of cells containing the text "(red)" (keeping in mind that my ultimate goal is to select the desired rows...turning them red is just a way of demonstrating that I've selected them), but all the selectors I've tried end up selecting more than the desired rows. I finally resorted to a filter function that did what I needed to do, but that seems a little awkward. Seems like there should be a better way.

```
<style>
.red-row {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('td:contains("(red)")').parent("tr:first").addClass('red-row');
    //$('td>:contains("(red)")').parent().addClass('red-row');
    $('td').filter(function(){var bob = $(this).text().indexOf("(red)"); return (bob > -1 && bob < 10);}).parent().addClass('red-row');
});
</script>

    <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h1>My Header</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     <h2>Left Column</h2>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                     <h2>Right Column</h2>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(red) Apple</td>
                                                <td>$3</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(yellow) Banana</td>
                                                <td>$2</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(yellow) Lemon</td>
                                                <td>$1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(red) Cherry</td>
                                                <td>$2</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(yellow) Quince</td>
                                                <td>$3</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>(green) Apple</td>
                                                <td>$4</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Some other content</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('td:contains("(red)")').not(':has(table)').closest("tr").addClass('red-row');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/deTpK/)

Comment: Ah, thanks for teaching me about the ":has" method. Very nice solution. Thank you very much.